# How do I change the position in scrim listener in collapsing toolbar layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

According to CollapsingToolbar documentation, a content scrim is:

A full-bleed scrim which is show or hidden when the scroll position has hit a certain threshold. You can change this via setContentScrim(Drawable).

Is there something like a setContentScrimThreshold I can assign in the layout file? I'd like the scrim to kick in sooner as the user scrolls up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for [`app:scrimVisibleHeightTrigger`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html#attr_CollapsingToolbarLayout_scrimVisibleHeightTrigger) and/or [`setScrimVisibleHeightTrigger()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html#setScrimVisibleHeightTrigger(int)).